# Cumulative sum based on date not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My target on daily basis is 250. For any given date, if the cum-daily_result has reached 250 then subsequent rows should have only 250 as expected results

**Input table:**

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       250     250
1   a       250     500
2   a       -1290   -790
3   b       -1392   -1392
4   b       250     -1142
5   b       250     -892
6   b       2238    1346
7   b       250     1596
8   c       2477    2477
9   c       -3813   -1336
10  c       250     -1086
```

If I use the following code, the output is correct if the first row col3 starts with a positive value

**Code:**

```
idx = df[df['col3'] >= 250].groupby('col1').head(1).index
df.loc[idx, 'col4'] = 1
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col4'].bfill() * df['col3']
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col4'].ffill().astype('int')
```

**Output:**

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   a       250     250     250
1   a       250     500     250
2   a       -1290   -790    250
3   b       -1392   -1392   -1392
4   b       250     -1142   -1142
5   b       250     -892    -892
6   b       2238    1346    1346
7   b       250     1596    1346
8   c       2477    2477    2477
9   c       -3813   -1336   2477
10  c       250     -1086   2477
```

But this is not working if the first row col3 is negative or all rows for specific col1 eg 'a' is negative.

Below is the example of input where the above code doesn't give desired result

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       -500     -500
1   a       -250     -750
2   a       -1000   -1750
3   b       -1392   -1392
4   b       250     -1142
5   b       250     -892
6   b       2238    1346
7   b       250     1596
8   c       2477    2477
9   c       -3813   -1336
10  c       250     -1086
```

**Expected output is as under**

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   a       -500     -500     -500
1   a       -250     -750     -750
2   a       -1000   -1750    -1750
3   b       -1392   -1392   -1392
4   b       250     -1142   -1142
5   b       250     -892    -892
6   b       2238    1346    1346
7   b       250     1596    1346
8   c       2477    2477    2477
9   c       -3813   -1336   2477
10  c       250     -1086   2477
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a less elegant solution, but it worked for me.

```
idx = df[df['col3'] >= 250].groupby('col1').head(1).index
df.loc[idx, 'col4'] = 1
df['col4']=df['col3']*df['col4']
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col4'].ffill()
df['col4']=df['col4'].fillna(df['col3']).astype('int')
```